# DB2 cardinatily estimation for BETWEEN predicate

Tags: db2

This is more of an academic question, since I´m interested in the details of DB2 query optimizer.

I got a table with 10000 records and no indexes. COLCARD in SYSCAT.TABLES is showing 10000 and a column named MesFabricacao has the following COLSTAT:

```
COLCARD HIGH2KEY    LOW2KEY     TABNAME      COLUMN

198         198         2       CARINFO     MESFABRICACAO
```

According to the core manual `“DB2PerfTuneTroubleshoot-db2d3e1011.pdf”` page 451 the cardinality formula for a between predicate with no histogram would be: `(( KEY2 - KEY1) / (HIGH2KEY - LOW2KEY)) * CARD`

For the given query `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATS.CARINFO WHERE MesFabricacao BETWEEN 1 AND 3"`, using `db2exfmt` I see a filter factor of 0.0151258, a value that I can´t explain why the QO is using for estimation.

Does anyone have an explanation on why DB2 is applying this filter factor? I´m using DB2 10.1.0.0.

(Output from db2exfmt)

### Predicates:

```
            2) Sargable Predicate,
                    Comparison Operator:            Less Than or Equal (<=)
                    Subquery Input Required:        No
                    Filter Factor:                  0.0151258

                    Predicate Text:
                    --------------
                    (Q1.MESFABRICACAO <= 3)

            3) Sargable Predicate,
                    Comparison Operator:            Less Than or Equal (<=)
                    Subquery Input Required:        No
                    Filter Factor:                  1

                    Predicate Text:
                    --------------
                    (1 <= Q1.MESFABRICACAO)

            Input Streams:
            -------------
                    1) From Object STATS.CARINFO

                            Estimated number of rows:       10000
                            Number of columns:              2
                            Subquery predicate ID:          Not Applicable

                            Column Names:
                            ------------
                            +Q1.$RID$+Q1.MESFABRICACAO

            Output Streams:
            --------------
                    2) To Operator #2

                            Estimated number of rows:       151.258
                            Number of columns:              0
```